# Wi-FI not working on ASUS U56E on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, scripts, asus

I don't think this is a huge problem because it seemed to be an easy fix for Ubuntu 11 and 12 so now I'm using 13.03 and cannot find a solution to my Wi-Fi problem.

My lap-top can find all the wireless networks in the area but it cannot connect to them at all. In Ubuntu 12 I used this script to connect to the wireless networks and it worked perfectly fine. I set it up so that whenever I started up Ubuntu this script would run allowing the Wi-Fi card to connect to the desired network:

```
echo "Type root password to enable wireless."
sudo modprobe -r iwlagn
sudo modprobe iwlagn
bt_coex_active=0
echo off
```

Now whenever I try to run that script this is what I get (I removed the `echo off` part of the script to get the output):

```
$ bash wifion.sh
Type root password to enable wireless.
[sudo] password for max: 
FATAL: Module iwlagn not found.
FATAL: Module iwlagn not found.
```

If you need any extra information please let me know and I will try to post that as well.

Thanks
Max Kulik

Comment: I guess I should also let you know know that the wired connection works perfectly fine and that I am using it right now.

Comment: In 13.04, the module is now known as iwlwifi. There are probably better ways to do what you are doing if you'd care to experiment.

Comment: Yeah I would have no problem doing that.

Comment: Really, it would just be nice to have my Wi-Fi working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create one text file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Add one line:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Reboot and tell us if it's working correctly now.

Comment: I have that file already and it contains things. Should I add that as the last line?

Comment: Yes, please, as its own separate line.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple. Sorry I have not responded sooner. It's has been getting very close to the end of the school year and exams are on. This has however worked so thanks a ton!

Comment: I wanted to just leave an updated note for people who are looking at this still. With Ubuntu 15.10, everything works. There is no need to mess around with anything any more.